# 404 Error after publishing Blazor WebApp in docker with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, blazor, .net-8.0

I had a Blazor WASM on .Net7 with nginx. It worked great. However, month ago I decided to update in to .net 8. And something goes wrong.
I decided to create a new Blazor WebApp for test from template, publish it and... failed again. 404 Not Found error.
Configuration is pretty simple. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["BlazorStandAlone8.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "BlazorStandAlone8.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "BlazorStandAlone8.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "BlazorStandAlone8.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish


FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /user/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/wwwroot .
COPY /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And my nginx.conf is

```
events { }
http {
   include mime.types;
   types {
      application/wasm;
    }
  server {
     listen 80;
     index index.html;
     location / {
        root /user/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
     }
  }
}
```

I run my container with this command: `docker run -p 5000:80 blazorsa8test`

I tried to play with ports, dockerfile configuration. I checked files inside docker container. It looks correct. I'd be grateful for any advice.

UPDATE: I figured out that problem is not in blazor or nginx. There is something with 5000 port. It works correctly with 5005 port. I'm not sure it's something with my local machine (e.x. confliect with another app/service). So, I continue the research.

Comment: try `/usr/share/nginx/html` instead of `user`

Comment: Unfortuantely, the same result: 404 Not found. Directory of app files is  `/usr/share/nginx/html`  now